# Using std::sort on a vector of objects doesn't work on compiler

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to sort a vector of objects. I have written a function to compare the objects. It seems to work fine on my compiler but not the one my school's server has.

```
bool sortByLastName(Student& lhs, Student& rhs) {
     string lhsLastName = lhs.getLastName();
     string rhsLastName = rhs.getLastName();
     return lhsLastName < rhsLastName;
}
```

I get this error...

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:131: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Student&’ from expression of type ‘const Student’
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:133: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Student&’ from expression of type ‘const Student’

I tried to make the arguments const String& but that also resulted in this error...

> Lab9Roster.cpp:79: error: passing ‘const Student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string Student::getLastName()’ discards qualifiers
>
> Lab9Roster.cpp:80: error: passing ‘const Student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string Student::getLastName()’ discards qualifiers

Comment: Why do you need non-const references to read last names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `getLastName` as

```
string getLastName() const;
```

and return

```
return lhs.getLastName() < rhs.getLastName();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you are passing temporary parameters like sortByLastName("s1", "s2"). However, though I doubt if it would work on some compilers, mostly non-const references don't bind to temporary objects. 
Use

```
bool sortByLastName(const Student& lhs,const Student& rhs) {
     string lhsLastName = lhs.getLastName();
     string rhsLastName = rhs.getLastName();
     return lhsLastName < rhsLastName;
}
```

Also, as @user3435400 has mentioned, define getLastName() as const, that is it cannot modify any class members

```
string getLastName() const;
```

Comment: Lab9Roster.cpp: In function ‘bool sortByLastName(const Student&, const Student&)’:
Lab9Roster.cpp:79: error: passing ‘const Student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string Student::getLastName()’ discards qualifiers
Lab9Roster.cpp:80: error: passing ‘const Student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string Student::getLastName()’ discards qualifiers

Comment: @BrucePucci: add `const` to those methods (like, `std::string getLastName() const { ... }`. and so on, if there are further `const` issues.

Comment: It works with this and user3435400's answer together. Thanks!